# I am using complex type as datamember of a datacontract

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I am using complex type as datamember of a datacontract. But the service is throwing an exception if i set [DataMember] to the complextype. What might be the reason. KIndly suggest. Below is the code snippet

```
[DataContract]
public class GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponseBody
{
    public GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponseBody()
    {
    }

    public GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponseBody
      (PatronAccountCardValidation GetDetailsFromCardNumberResult)
    {
        this.GetDetailsFromCardNumberResult = GetDetailsFromCardNumberResult;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public PatronAccountCardValidation GetDetailsFromCardNumberResult { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name="PatronAccountCardValidation")]
public class PatronAccountCardValidation
{
    [DataMember]
    public Patron Patron { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Card Card { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BonusDollarLocal { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BonusDollarRemote { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Valid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MessageText { get; set; }        
}
```

Check the parameter `PatronAccountCardValidation`.

Check property `Card`. It is causing an issue. Please help.

Error received:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP
>   response to localhost:9090/DoorAccessAndVendingMachineService. This
>   could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
>   aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
>   server logs for more details

Comment: All your classes you're using in your contract has DataContract attribute (Patron, Card, ...)?

Comment: Yes... Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:9090/DoorAccessAndVendingMachineService. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Comment: That is the nastiest exception you get with WCF. Actual exception on server side is hidden. You should enable tracing on server side and look for underlying exception. To enable tracing follow this guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: 2 things: show us the config file. Have you added an urlacl for http with netsh?

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider to apply Data Contract Know types? It allows you to specify, in advance, the types that should be included for consideration during deserialization. And by default during deserialization, an uninitialized object is first created, without calling any constructors on the type. Then all data members are deserialized. See more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(PatronAccountCardValidation))]
public class GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponseBody
{
    public GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponseBody()
    {
    }

    public GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponseBody
      (PatronAccountCardValidation GetDetailsFromCardNumberResult)
    {
        this.GetDetailsFromCardNumberResult = GetDetailsFromCardNumberResult;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public PatronAccountCardValidation GetDetailsFromCardNumberResult { get; set; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(Card))]
[KnownType(typeof(Patron))]
[DataContract(Name="PatronAccountCardValidation")]
public class PatronAccountCardValidation
{
    [DataMember]
    public Patron Patron { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Card Card { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BonusDollarLocal { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BonusDollarRemote { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Valid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MessageText { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I didn't saw that you have lots of objects. If still doesn't work. Try to add KnowTypes on GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponseBody.